# How can I remove Thumbs.db files

Tags: windows-7, thumbs.db

How can I remove Thumbs.db files from Window 7 without affecting any other files? I have already turned off indexing as I use a program called Everything for searches.

Comment: Yes, the file can simply be deleted.

Comment: Thumbs.db files are NOT created by indexing, they are created when you wish to view files by thumbnails.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try this one-liner in PowerShell:

```
get-childitem c:\ -include thumbs.db -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

By the way, you can replace "C:\" with a different starting folder if you don't want to search the entire drive.

Answer (score 1):

Save this to file with `.bat` extension and run. It'll go through every folder on drive C:\ and `del` existing every file with name `thumbs.db`.

```
echo off
for /R "c:\" %%i in (thumbs.db) do (
    if exist %%i del %%i
)
```

or

Use Explorer's search bar, type `"thumbs.db"`, wait till it finds every occurence, then select all `ctrl + a` and `delete`